# Convert string to date format in Stata

Tags: string, date, stata

I have a column of string variables e.g. 2010m07, and I would like to convert them into a date format in Stata. How do I go about this?

Comment: Just asking for code without an attempt is widely considered off-topic here. Otherwise SO could just be a series of requests for code.

Answer (score 1):

You can a map a single string variable (a variable in Stata is an entire column in spreadsheet terms) to a numeric date variable with an appropriate date function. In your case

```
gen mdate = monthly(mystring, "YM") 
format mdate %tm
```

Note that a date format here is just a display format to make a date intelligible to people; the date variable itself is numeric.

This is all documented in detail: `help datetime`.

A way of doing this in one is `numdate` from SSC. Once installed, you can go

```
numdate monthly mdate = mystring, pattern(YM)
```

and the subcommand `monthly` suffices to apply `%tm` as a default format. If you want a different format, you can specify it. (If a reference to SSC makes no sense, `help ssc`.)